# Spring Security Filters with AntPathRequestMatcher

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a authentication filter which extends spring security, **AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter** .
So in this case I can set the request matcher as below,

```
MyAuthenticationFilter authFilter = new MyAuthenticationFilter();
authFilter.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**"));
```

I create another filter does not necessary to have a authentication functionality. So I extend it using **GenericFilterBean**. In this case how I can add AntPathRequestMatcher as above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to invoke `RequestMatcher.matches(HttpServletRequest request)`

```
RequestMatcher myMatcher = AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**");
...


@Override
void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain chain) {

   if (myMatcher.matches(request)) {
       ...
   } else {
       ... 
   }

   chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Comment: Any way to have multiple paths in the pattern ? Say either the `web` or `api` path. Would that regexp `"/web|api/**"` do it ?